# Plupload + AngularJS UI modal doesn't work in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, plupload

I've already seen a lot of articles about plupload and modal dialogs in old versions of IE, but any of them had a solution for my problem. I'm using AngularJS UI to open modals which contain the container div of plupload, and I need to do this work in this way.

I've tried all the solutions: uploader.refresh(), I've used require.js to load the plupload script when the dialog was already opened, but I still haven't found one that works.

Here's  the function of the controller that calls the modal dialog:

```
$scope.EnviarNovoAnexoClick = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/Dialog/EnviarAnexo',
            controller: 'EnviarAnexoDialogController',
            resolve: {
                documentoId: function () {
                    return $scope.documentoId;
                }                    
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (anexo) {
            $scope.documento.anexos.push(anexo);
        }, function () {//dismiss callback
        });
    }
```

Here's the function that calls the uploader:

```
require(["/Scripts/plupload.full.js"], function (util) {
        $scope.anexoUploader = new plupload.Uploader({
            runtimes: 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus,html4',
            browse_button: 'anexoBtUpload',
            container: 'anexoUploadDiv',
            unique_names: true,
            multi_selection: false,
            max_file_size: '150mb',
            chunk_size: '64kb',
            url: '/Documento/Upload',
            flash_swf_url: '/Scripts/plupload.flash.swf',
            silverlight_xap_url: '/Scripts/plupload.silverlight.xap',
            resize: { width: 320, height: 240, quality: 90 },
            filters: [
                    { title: "PDFs ", extensions: "pdf" },
                    { title: "Imagens", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" },
                    { title: "Zips", extensions: "zip" },
                    { title: "Todos", extensions: "*" }
            ],
            init: {
                FilesAdded: function (up, files) {
                    if ($scope.uploadDocumento == null) {
                        $scope.showOrigemAnexo = false;
                        $scope.novoAnexo.upload = {};
                        $scope.InicializaUpload($scope.novoAnexo.upload);
                        $scope.uploadDocumento = $scope.novoAnexo.upload;
                    }

                    var fileName = $scope.anexoUploader.files[$scope.anexoUploader.files.length - 1].name;

                    $scope.uploadDocumento.nome = fileName;
                    $scope.novoAnexo.descricao = dotlessName(fileName);
                    $scope.$apply();

                    up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
                    up.start();
                },
                UploadProgress: function (up, file) {
                    $scope.uploadDocumento.size = file.size;
                    $scope.uploadDocumento.percentage = file.percent;
                    $scope.$apply();
                },
                FileUploaded: function (up, file, response) {
                    $scope.uploadDocumento.id = file.id;
                    $scope.uploadDocumento.size = file.size;
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            }
        });

        $scope.anexoUploader.init();
    });
```

The file dialog is opening in Chrome, IE10 and Firefox, but I need that it works on IE9 and 8.

Thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with caching and dynamically loaded script tag.

Solution that worked for me:

Add this directive:

```
.directive('cachedTemplate', ['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
  "use strict";
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    terminal: true,
    compile: function (element, attr) {
      if (attr.type === 'text/ng-template') {
        var templateUrl = attr.cachedTemplate,
            text = element.html();
        $templateCache.put(templateUrl, text);
      }
    }
  };
}])
```

Declare your modal content in

```
<div data-cached-template="myInnerModalContent.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

You may need this style as well:

```
*[type="text/ng-template"]{
    display: none;
}
```

In controller:

```
$scope.open = function() {
          var modalInstance = $modal.open({
              templateUrl: 'ModalContent.html',
              controller: modalInstanceCtrl
          });
        };
```

Reference: http://blog.tomaszbialecki.info/ie8-angularjs-script-cache-problem/